# Split Dataframe by Cut-off, assign 1 vs 0 in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset(df) that looks a follows:

[image]

I have split df by the miR21 cutoff of 8 in dfn21h (>= 8) and dfn21l (< 8).

Now I want to split df by the cutoff of 8 (miR21) and ad a new column ('group') to my dataset with 1 for >= 8 and 0 for < 8.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: the question is unclear, what is `dfn21h`?, do you want `df['group'] = df['miR21'].ge(8).astype(int)`?

Comment: @mozway dfn21h is miR21 > 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your column (`col`), change its type to int (since you want 1, 0 in your post), then add it to the data frame. There are probably more compact ways to do this, but this should work.

```
col = df['miR21'] > 8
col.name = 'group'
df['group'] = col.astype(int)
```

Update: to use a general name instead, do this:

```
newcol = [ 'control' ] * len(df) # Create a new column that's all 'control'
df['group'] = newcol
df.loc[df['miR21'] > 8, 'group'] = 'test'
```

The last line says, if df['miR21'] > 8, then change the 'group' value to 'test'

Comment: thanks a lot. How can I not just assign an 1 or 0 but for example name it control vs test.

Comment: Okay - editing answer to add that